Granting group write permission to a specific folder
I'd like other users in my group to be able to access a specific folder in my filespace (and its subfolders), without being able to access the rest of my files.
[The reason is that I want to compile an instrumented application to do code-coverage using gcov; the various .gcno files get written to my build directory, and I'd like my colleagues, while running their tests, both to access these files and generate the .gcda files which will be placed alongside them.]
Anyway, I'd naively thought I could just do:
chmod g+w -fR build_directory

...and sure enough this results in the build directory and all its subdirectories having permissions drwxrwxr-x. and all its files having permissions -rw-rw-r--. Even so, my colleagues in the group report that even trying to execute
ls -l <full path to build_directory>

returns "Cannot access: No such file or directory".
What am I missing?

Directory permissions on the path to your target directory are the problem. The group needs x permissions to traverse the directories. Explore your Mount/Read/Write/Execute problems with https://github.com/waltinator/pathlld, a bash script to show the permissions, mount options along the path to an object or objects. Also read man 3 chmod to educate yourself about permisdions for directories.

Thank you; but all the directories in the hierarchy have at minimum drwxr-xr-x., i.e. executable for all groups, while the ones I want to share have drwxrwxr-x. I tried out your bash script which was a very neat way of visualising the hierarchy, but I'm not sure I'm any the wiser about the basic accessibility problem.

What type of filesystem are you using?  sudo lsblk -f. Are yyou sure that the other users are in the group? Did they, and you logoff/logon after you changed the groups? [Edit], don't Add Comment.

Have everybody use the id command to check group membership.  Have a user that can't access run pathlld on a file i. the target directory.

Hm. Strangely the site doesn't let me edit my earlier comment. Anyway, the use who's been trying to do this is definitely in the group - I've checked using 'id' - but logging out then in again is worth trying. The individual in question is on holiday today, but I'll find someone else to try it out.

I have found the solution, and it is embarrassing.
There was nothing wrong with my permissions. The issue was that the drive upon which the directory resides was local to the server that I was running on, and not a network drive. My colleagues were working on other servers, so my server's network drive wasn't visible to them at all.
No wonder that the error message was "Cannot access: No such file or directory."
When my colleagues logged into their accounts on the same server, so that the local disk was visible, everything worked as expected.
EDIT: I subsequently found that to get the exact result that I really wanted - full group read/write access to one particular directory within my home directory whilst keeping the rest of my home directory private - what I needed to do was to ensure that all the directories above the public one had group execute permission, but not read/write permission. In other words, given the tree:
/home/me/this/is/a/very/long/directory/path/leading/to/a_public/folder/the_public_folder

...then  I got the desired effect with
chmod 710 /home/me/this/is/a/very/long/directory/path/leading/to/a_public/folder
chmod 710 /home/me/this/is/a/very/long/directory/path/leading/to/a_public
chmod 710 /home/me/this/is/a/very/long/directory/path/leading/to
chmod 710 /home/me/this/is/a/very/long/directory/path/leading
chmod 710 /home/me/this/is/a/very/long/directory/path
chmod 710 /home/me/this/is/a/very/long/directory
chmod 710 /home/me/this/is/a/very/long
chmod 710 /home/me/this/is/a/very
chmod 710 /home/me/this/is/a
chmod 710 /home/me/this/is
chmod 710 /home/me/this
chmod 710 /home/me
chmod 770 -fR /home/me/this/is/a/very/long/directory/path/leading/to/a_public/folder/the_public_folder

